# Issues of Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck creating a navigation bar. I dont know why the text is out of the bar? Can anyone what is the problem?

[image]

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/*Menu*/

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 2px 6px 0;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  justify-content: space-between;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arvo;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #27D05F;
  transition: ease 1s;
  color: #fff;
}


/*Dropdownmenu*/
nav ul li ul li {
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 2px 6px 0;
}

nav ul:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Aunty Grocery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="w3-container w3-center w3-animate-left">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="grocery.html">Grocery</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="vegetables.html">Vegetables</a></li>
          <li><a href="meats.html">Meats</a></li>
          <li><a href="fish.html">Fish</a></li>
          <li><a href="fruits.html">Fruits</a></li>
          <li><a href="bakery.html">Bakery</a></li>
          <li><a href="others.html">Others</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="career.html">Career</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <a class="Register" href="Register.html"><button>Sign Up</button></a>
  <a class="Login" href="Login.html"><button>Sign In</button></a>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because the sub-level `ul` is making all the `li` taller. To keep the alignment to the top of the `ul` you need to set `vertical-align: top`:

```
nav ul li {
  /* other properties... */
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/*Menu*/

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 2px 6px 0;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  justify-content: space-between;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arvo;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #27D05F;
  transition: ease 1s;
  color: #fff;
}


/*Dropdownmenu*/

nav ul li ul li {
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 2px 6px 0;
}

nav ul:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<nav class="w3-container w3-center w3-animate-left">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="grocery.html">Grocery</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="vegetables.html">Vegetables</a></li>
        <li><a href="meats.html">Meats</a></li>
        <li><a href="fish.html">Fish</a></li>
        <li><a href="fruits.html">Fruits</a></li>
        <li><a href="bakery.html">Bakery</a></li>
        <li><a href="others.html">Others</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="career.html">Career</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<a class="Register" href="Register.html"><button>Sign Up</button></a>
<a class="Login" href="Login.html"><button>Sign In</button></a>
```

Comment: thank you, u solve my problem.